# regular expression for strings with specific values

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to match strings that start with an `M` and end with an `F` having one or more of `CD` or `EF` in the body of the string. My current attempt is:

```
^M[CD|EF]*$F
```

Example string is: `M 123ABNCDandEF78949XZ F`.

I am getting "match not found". Any suggestions..

Comment: Should `MxxxxEF` match?

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor correctly, use the correct grouping and repetition syntax
and allow for presence of other characters. See this:

```
import re
re.search(r'^M.*(CD|EF)+.*F$', "M 123ABNCDandEF78949XZ F").group()
'M 123ABNCDandEF78949XZ F'
```